# QString line.split

Tags: c++, qt

I am having trouble with split function on QT. I have a text file and the very first line is like this:

```
10,100;100,100;100,100;100,200;100,200;300,200;300,200;300,350;300,350;250,350;250,350;250,300;250,300;200,300;200,300;200,400;200,400;10,400;10,400;10,100
```

Here every two numbers represents a point with x an y values and semicolons divides the points. After every semicolon there is a new point.

What I want to do is split these numbers element by element like;

Element 0: 10 
Element 1: 100 
Element 2: 100 
Element 3: 100 
...

I have managed to do this but there wasn't any semicolons or colons in the text file.

First line of the text file:

```
10 100 100 100 100 200 300 200 300 350 250 350 250 300 200 300 200 400 10 400 10 100
```

This is how i did it:

```
void Dialog::readFile()
{
    QFile file("/Path/of/the/text/file/Data.txt");

    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::information(0, "info", file.errorString());
    }

    QString line = file.readLine();
    qDebug() << "line:" << line << "\n";
    QStringList list = line.split(" ");
    double element;

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        element = list.at(i).toDouble();
        points_.append(element);
        qDebug() << "element:" << element << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output of this code is:

```
line: "10 100 100 100 100 200 300 200 300 350 250 350 250 300 200 300 200 400 10 400 10 100\r" 
element: 10 
element: 100 
element: 100 
element: 100 
element: 100 
element: 200 
element: 300 
element: 200 
....
```

I want to do this exactly the same way. Is there any suggestion?

PS: I am new on QT so please consider this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression with the [`QString::split`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split-3) overload taking [`QRegExp`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html) or the next one taking [`QRegularExpression`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html):

```
QStringList list = line.split(QRegExp(",|;")); // ",|;" matches ',' or ';'
```

`QRegExp` is called to be deprecated, but it can do the job here.

Comment: Alternatively, one can split first by ";", then by ","